Is sudoku only one puzzle?
Consider a graph G where each node represents a possible Sudoku solution. We define edges between nodes based on the application of specific "equivalent transformations" that map one solution to another. These transformations include:

relabeling numbers;
reflection;
rotation;
permutation of blocks of columns (1-3, 4-6, 7-9);
permutation of blocks of rows (1-3, 4-6, 7-9);
permutation of columns within each block (1-3, 4-6, 7-9) and
permutation of rows within each block (1-3, 4-6, 7-9).

So: an edge is drawn between two nodes if one solution can be transformed into the other by applying any of these transformations.
Given this construction, is the resulting graph G connected? In other words, is there a path between any two nodes in the graph?

The title question matches the body: it's just a little clickbaity/provocative. It could be soften to "Can Sudokus be seen as equivalent problems in the following framework?" Or maybe more direct would be: "Is this Graph of Sudoku puzzles connected?"

I think the answer has to be "no..." you can probably find a [uninformative] proof of this just via combinatorics. Count how many Sudokus are possible. Count how many ways we can modify a sudoku into equivalent forms and then when they give different numbers... but I think you might be able to just come up with a counter example on perhaps a smaller version of sudoku like the 4x4 and then scale up. +1 for your first question.

If you define for two values $T_{i,j}$ for $1\leq i<j\leq9$ as the number of rows and columns such that $i,j$ are in the same third of the row/column, then, then the multiset of all $ T_{ij}$ values will be the same if any of your incremental changes occur. So you just need to find $2$ answers that yield different multiset.

There's an interesting dual problem which is something about the minimum amount needed to uniquely specify a sudoku down to equivalence group? Or, given a valid sudoku solution, to transform it into a 'regular form' such that all equivalent sudokus have the same regular form? like, you can arbitrarily fix the upper left block to be 123456789 (because relabeling) but that doesn't eliminate permutation of the middle and bottom block's rows.

@NotThatGuy I think there's a consensus that "relabeling numbers" means taking a permutation on the set ${0,1,...,9}$, and applying that permutation uniformly to all cells in the puzzle. For example, taking all cells and replacing their contents with their complement (1 replaced to 9, 2 replaced to 8, etc). This is a known symmetry which does not change the logical content of the sudoku. As a non-example, relabeling an individual cell without changing anything else would not be a valid instance of this relabeling scheme. Though, I can see how one would get confused on this.

No, it is not the case. In the comments, Thomas Andrews suggests an invariant: for $1\leq i<j\leq 9$, define $T_{i,j}$ as the number of rows and columns such that $i,j$ are in the same third. The multiset consisting of all the $T_{i,j}$ values does not change under any of the listed symmetries. Because of this, we get a negative answer so long as we find two puzzles which differ under this invariant. Below are two explicit puzzles which differ in that way.

It's very easy to verify this sudoku, since each block is practically identical under translation. In this first puzzle, we can see that for any two numbers $i\neq j$, we either have $i$ and $j$ in the same third for all $9$ blocks, or else we never have $i,j$ in the same third of any block whatsoever. Using the invariant established previously, we see $T_{i,j}\in\{0,9\}$ for all $i,j$, and so the multiset of all the $T_{i,j}$ values doesn't contain any numbers besides $0$s and $9$s. The following puzzle violates this rule.

In the above puzzle, we can see that $1,7$ are in the same third in the top left block, but not in the middle block, so in particular $T_{1,7}\notin \{0,9\}$. If you're concerned about verifying this sudoku, you can use practically any solved puzzle to replace this second example. Most solved puzzles aren't nearly as organized as my first example.

Another simple invariant is the number of rectangles (four cells that form the intersection of any two rows and any two columns) that contain only two values. In an unsolved sudoku problem at least one of those four cells will have to be given as a clue since otherwise the values could be swapped. This invariant doesn't distinguish the pair of sudokus you've given though.

An invariant which is more complicated but is better at distinguishing sudokus. Say a $1$ and a $2$ are in the same cycle if they are in the same row or same column. Define the $1,2$-cycle structure as the multiset of counts of $1$s in these cycles. Define cycle structures for other value-pairs likewise. Then the multiset of the 36 cycle structures is an invariant.

@RosieF The invariant I mentioned in my previous comment is essentially just how many fours occur in the multisets of your invariant.

This answer should be edited to include a definition of the invariant. Referring to a comment is not a good idea, since comments can be deleted at any time for almost any reason.

Hi. On stackexchange, comments tend to disappear mysteriously and silently. Could you please include a definition of $T_{i,j}$ in the answer?

Answer has been edited to include the definition of the invariant. Thanks for the suggestions, I didn't think of it :)

According to Wikipedia, for classical Sudoku, the number of validly filled grids is $6{,}670{,}903{,}752{,}021{,}072{,}936{,}960 \approx6.671×10^{21}$, which reduces to $5{,}472{,}730{,}538$ essentially different solutions under the equivalence transformations.
A direct reference for this is the 2006 paper of Russell & Jarvis.

There two are different:


The first one has no rectangle with only two values.
The second one has rectangles with only two values (highlighted in yellow).
By rectangle I mean the intersection of two rows and two columns.

Ummm. Both have many, many, many "rectangles with only two values". Can you be more specific as to what is significant about those two rectangles?

@PaulSinclair That is only one rectangle labelled in yellow. Those are the corners. In sudoku terminology that is an X-wing and is not solvable uniquely (when contained within only two boxes like that) without knowing one of the digits already. All the transformations listed in the question preserve X-wings. The first puzzle can be seen not to have any as the digits increase (cyclically) across each row.

@PaulSinclair a "proper" rectangle (spanning more than one row and more than one column, so it has four distinct corners) with only two distinct values in the corners.

Note this is exactly the invariant described in Jaap Scherphuis' comment

This answer is very similar to the one by @JadeVanadium (+1), but with explicit Sudoku solutions and verification, replaced by constructions and argument.  I think it is nice to have both.
A completed Sudoku is precisely a function $f\colon {\mathbb{F}_3}^4\to {\mathbb{F}_3}^2$ satisfying that for any $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\in {\mathbb{F}_3}$ the following maps are bijections:
$$
(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y,a_3,a_4),\\(x,y)\mapsto f(a_1,a_2,x,y),\\(x,y)\mapsto f(x,a_2,y,a_4).
$$
These three conditions are just the usual restrictions that rows, columns, and blocks contain distinct entries.
Thus one solution is $f(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(a_1+a_4,a_2+a_3)$.
This generalises to the family of solutions $f^\lhd(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(a_1+a_4,(a_1\lhd a_2)+a_3)$ where for $i\in \mathbb{F}_3$, we have $i\lhd \in S_{\mathbb{F}_3}$.
Let $C$ be the set of $54$ lines in ${\mathbb{F}_3}^4$ the form $(*,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ or $(a_1,a_2,*,a_4)$ (where the $a_i$ are fixed values).  For a completed Sudoku $h$, let $N(h)$ denote the number of distinct images of elements of $C$: $$N(h)=|\{h(I)\subset {\mathbb{F}_3}^2\vert\,\, I\in C\}|.$$
Transformation 1 will relabel the images $h(I)$, but not change the number of them.  We claim the remaining transformations permute the elements of $C$, so also do not effect $N(h)$:
Transformation 2 consists of maps of the form $$\qquad\,\,\,\,(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto (-a_1,-a_2,a_3,a_4)\\{\rm or}\qquad (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto (a_1,a_2,-a_3,-a_4) $$
These clearly preserve elements of $C$.
Transformation 3 consists of maps of the form $$\qquad\,\,\,\,(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto (a_3,a_4,-a_1,-a_2)\\{\rm or}\qquad\qquad (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto (-a_3,-a_4,a_1,a_2)\\{\rm or}\qquad (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto (-a_1,-a_2,-a_3,-a_4)\,\,\,  $$
These also preserve elements of $C$, with the first two interchanging the lines of the form $(*,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ with the lines of the form $(a_1,a_2,*,a_4)$.
Transformations 4 and 5 have the form:$$\qquad\,\,\,\,(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto (a_1,\sigma(a_2),a_3,a_4)\\{\rm or}\qquad (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto (a_1,a_2,a_3,\sigma(a_4)) $$
respectively, for some $\sigma\in S_{\mathbb{F}_3}$.  Clearly these also preserve elements of $C$.
Transformations 6 and 7 have the form:$$\qquad\,\,\,\,(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto (\sigma_{a_2}(a_1),a_2,a_3,a_4)\\{\rm or}\qquad (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \mapsto (a_1,a_2,\sigma_{a_4}(a_3),a_4) $$
respectively, for $\sigma_i\in S_{\mathbb{F}_3}$ which depend on the parameter $i$.  These preserve elements of $C$.  Note these make a complete mess of lines of the form, $(a_1,*,a_3,a_4)$ or $(a_1,a_2,a_3,*)$, which is why we defined $C$ the way we did.
We conclude that $N$ is invariant on equivalence classes of completed Sudoku's.
Now $N(f)= 6$, as the images of elements of $C$ under $f$ are just the horizontal or vertical lines in ${\mathbb{F}_3}^2$.
It remains to find a product $ \lhd\colon \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F_3} \to \mathbb{F_3}$ such that $N(f^\lhd)\neq 6$.  Recall, the only constraint we placed on $\lhd$ in order for $f^\lhd$ to be a valid Sudoku solution was for $i\in \mathbb{F}_3$, we have $i\lhd \in S_{\mathbb{F}_3}$.
Thus $$i\lhd j = (-1)^{\delta_{0i}}j,$$ gives us a valid Sudoku solution $f^\lhd$, where $\delta$ is the usual Kronecker delta.
The lines $(a_1,a_2,*,a_4)$ map to the $3$ vertical lines in ${\mathbb{F}_3}^2$ just as they did under $f$.  Also the lines $(*,0,a_3,a_4)$ map to the same $3$ horizontal lines as they did under $f$.  However $(*,1,0,0)$ maps to the set: $$\{(0,2),(1,1),(2,1)\}.$$  This is neither a vertical nor horizontal line, so we have $N(f^\lhd)>6$.  Thus $f$ and $f^\lhd$ are nonequivalent Sudoku solutions.  (In fact it is easy to see that the $18$ elements of $C$ which do not map to horizontal or vertical lines all map to distinct images in ${\mathbb{F}_3}^2$, so $N(f^\lhd)=24$).
In conventional Sudoku terms, $f$ is essentially the first solution in Jade Vanadium's answer, and we obtain $f^\lhd$ from $f$ by swapping the 2nd and 7th columns.  This transformation does not in general preserve solutions, but it does in this case because $f$ has so much symmetry.  The set $C$ is just the set of thirds, so the invariant $N$ is very similar to the one in Jade Vanadium's answer.  In fact it is clear that if you swap the 1st and 4th columns in Jade Vanadium's first solution, then the pair $1,2$ will occur in the same third in precisely $5\notin\{0,9\}$ of the boxes.

What does "$\lhd\in$” mean in “$i\lhd\in S_{\Bbb F_3}$?

It is shorthand for saying that the map sending $j\mapsto i\lhd j$ is a permutation.
